# Python `requests.Session()`: response headers not showing `Set-Cookie` headers

Tags: python, python-requests

I was following the tutorial over at https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/ regarding the `requests.Session()`. I tried to access the response headers for the HTTP GET request that is expected to return a `Set-Cookie` header. However, it doesn't show. I am running Python 3.12 and requests@2.31.0 incase that might be the issue.

```py
  s = requests.Session()
 
  r = s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
  print(r.headers) # does not display set-cookie
```

I was expecting the `Set-Cookie` header to display. I have also tried the opposite, where the `r.headers` display the `Set-Cookie` headers correctly, but the `r.request.headers` for another request right after does not display the `Cookie` header

```py
  r1 = s.get("https://google.com")
  print(r1.headers) # displays set-cookie
  
  r2  = s.get("https://httpbin.org/cookies")
  print(r2.request.headers # does not display cookie
```

Comment: The URL uses a redirect. So it is basically two requests. You can see the header in the first request: `r.history[0].headers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookies will be present in  session

So,

```
print(s.cookies)
```

`s.cookies` attribute is used to see the cookies stored in the session

or you can use `r1.text`to get cookies https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/

***Note:**The Cookie header in the request is managed automatically by the `requests`  library based on the cookies in the session's cookie*

Comment: oh right, thank you! After viewing the `s.cookies`, i realised that i can actually view the cookies stored for each endpoints i sent a request to.

Comment: I understand that `r1.text` in the first example (`https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789` ) would return the cookies as it configured that way for httpbin.org for testing purposes. However, why does viewing the response.headers not show the `set-cookie` headers?

Answer (score 1):

When you make a request to set the cookies on httpbin.org it is actually returning a [302 response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) to you with the set cookie header redirecting you back to https://httpbin.org/cookies

What requests does is that it automatically follows this redirect and makes another request. So when you write `r.headers` you are looking at the response headers of the second response. If you change the code and set `allow_redirects=False` you will be able to see the "Set-Cookie" header:

```py
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789', allow_redirects=False)
print(r.headers) # Displays Set-Cookie
```

When you write `r2.request.headers` you're actually looking at the **request** headers, i.e. the headers that the **client** (Your code) sent to the server, it makes sense that no "Set-Cookie" headers are shown there.

If you want to look at the cookies saved by the session you should simply be looking at `s.cookies` i.e. the sessions cookies attribute. This will allow you to access all the cookies stored by the session.

Comment: oh right, that makes sense now. Thank you!